# Extract Attribute-based XML using PL SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have some attribute XML file that is stored in DB in CLOB format. The length of the clob column varies, ranging from 200 to 9000. Since xmltype is not working with CLOB directly I have to convert the clob into string and then pass it into xmltype. Is there any alternative to that? Because when the clob is converted to string it can hold max 4000 character and the XML is not properly parsed then

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which db version you are on - I've tried on 10, 11, and 12. It works fine with clob. Here is my example

```
create table some_table(num_col number, clob_col clob);

declare 
  clob_var clob := to_clob('... a long long clob ...'); -- works smoothly without "to_clob" as well
begin
  insert into some_table values(1, clob_var);
end;
```

I used the xml example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85))
so, the query

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(t.clob_col).EXTRACT('//book/genre').getStringVal()
  FROM some_table t;
```

gave me the following

```
<genre>Computer</genre>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<genre>Romance</genre>
<genre>Romance</genre>
<genre>Horror</genre>
<genre>Science Fiction</genre>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<genre>Computer</genre>
```

Thus, I think you should give xmltype a try to process your clob data as it seems to be working fine with that type of data